# How to say "can't distinguish"?

Tags: word, phrase

About a year and a half ago, I remember learning a Mandarin phrase for "can't distinguish between", but I don't remember what it was and I no longer have my textbook. In my mind, I'm getting it mixed up with phrases 分别 and 看不清楚. What is the best way to say "can't distinguish between" or "can't tell the difference"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**分不清**

I think that's the mix of 分别 and 看不清楚 that you're looking for.